# Jquery token input autocomplete not working on facebook friends array with rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a text field with autocomplete from your facebook friends using this tutorial:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields?autoplay=true

i get in the js console this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
highlight_termjquery.tokeninput.js:609
$.TokenList.selected_dropdown_itemjquery.tokeninput.js:628
jQuery.extend.eachjquery.js:641
populate_dropdownjquery.tokeninput.js:627
run_searchjquery.tokeninput.js:704
$.TokenList.ajax_params

my code is:

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#when").datetimepicker();
  $("#who").tokenInput("/memberships.json", {
    crossDomain: false,
    theme: "facebook"
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<% form_for @doweet, :html => { :id => "post" } do |f| %>

<%= error_messages_for @doweet %>

<%= f.text_field :doweet_member_tokens,  :id => "who", :placeholder => "Who?" %>  

<%= f.submit "Doweet" %>
```

rails:

memberships.json:

```
q = params[:q]
@friend_members = FbGraph::Query.new("SELECT name,uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name asc").fetch(current_user.token).collect { |f| f["name"] }.select { |v| v =~ /#{Regexp.escape(q)}/i  } 
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @friend_members }
end
```

i'm getting back from this an array like this: ["Shlomi Caduri","Shlomit Harth"]

doweet.rb:

```
  attr_reader :doweet_member_tokens

  def doweet_member_tokens=(ids)
    self.doweet_member_ids = ids.split(",")
  end
```

the js and css files are attached properly.

the problem is that when i search a name i don't see a results and if i go manuly to localhost:3000/memberships.json?q=asdf i see... i think the problem is in the JS...

what i do wrong?

thanks a lot,

gal

Comment: You don't really explain what the problem is..

Comment: the problem is that when i search a name i don't see a results and if i go manuly to localhost:3000/memberships.json?q=asdf i see... i think the problem is in the JS...

Comment: open the js console, what do you see?

Comment: this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
highlight_termjquery.tokeninput.js:609
$.TokenList.selected_dropdown_itemjquery.tokeninput.js:628
jQuery.extend.eachjquery.js:641
populate_dropdownjquery.tokeninput.js:627
run_searchjquery.tokeninput.js:704
$.TokenList.ajax_params

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this problem as well and it had to do with the model column name. Jquery TokenInput requires an array of ID, NAME pairs in its json response. if the column you are trying to access is named something else, or your json response only includes names, you will get the replace error.

Comment: the ID,Name is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#who").tokenInput("/memberships.json", {
    crossDomain: false,
    theme: "facebook",
    propertyToSearch: "yourJSONfieldname"
  });
```

If your json results doesn't have a 'name' attribute to show in the drowdown, then make sure you specify using the propertyToSearch attribute.